# Is it possible to send a Users Location from an iOS App to a Webserver?

Tags: swift, xcode, webserver, mapkit, core-location

I´m new to coding and programming and I have basically no knowledge, but my task is to create an iOS App.
I am working in an app project and the goal is to create an Emergency-App. The idea is that if you open the app, there is one button that you have to press for 2 seconds to send an Emergency call to a Web-Server, including the CoreLocation of the user and if possible also the floor where the user´s currently at. (As mentioned, I have no idea whether it is possible, thats why I am asking)

I also read that some people sent the location with an sms to a phone number.

So if any of you guys could help me on how to send the location to a web server that would be very helpfull! Or if you have an advice for me thats helpfull as well !

Thanks in common!

I haven´t really tried anything yet because i don´t know how.

Comment: Sending location to server is possible using the iOS App. first go through the apple core location api and its delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. The api is on the Apple Website isn´t it ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation

Comment: @MarloManger Check [How To Get the User Location](https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

Comment: Please do not put argumentative statements in the body of the question. If you have an issue with its closure, you can bring that up in the comments. Additionally, questions closed as off-topic have a further reason listed in the closure reason.

Comment: okay I am sorry no one told me that. so shall I delete my question or what ? It seems to me that I have upset some people by asking my question haha. But I got a n idea for y'all: Just tell me the do's and dont's beforehand!

Comment: I want you to explain to me how my question causes: "tend to attract opinioated answers and spam". I really don't get it sorry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From beginning, First set location Autorization status: 
For that you need to specify permission in info.plist.

After the user will allow location services you will be able to get the real location coordinate on real device, if you want to simulate the location you can do it on simulator.

CoreLocation is the framework which Apple provide to access the location service. You sometime need to turn on the location capabilities.

You will have LocationManager class which does all you need. It also has delegate method that will give you all update of location, you can save current location in UserDefault everytime update comes.

When user press button you can send those coordinates from UserDefault